# undefined method `build_book_reservation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session

hi im just wondering if why the session cant find my reservation upon refresh and used it in a other controller

this is my applicationcontroller

```
  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time


     private
 def current_reservation
   @reservation ||= Reservation.find(session[:reservation_id]) if session[:reservation_id]
   #last assigned value will be returned as default.
 end

 def create_reservation_session(id)
   session[:reservation_id] = id
 end

 def destroy_reservation_session
   session[:reservation_id] = nil
 end
```

and im trying to us it here

```
 def new
   @book_reservation = BookReservation.new
 end

def create
  @reservation = current_reservation
  @book_reservation=@reservation.build_book_reservation(params[:book_reservation])
  if @book_reservation.save
    #If success set session
    create_reservation_session(@reservation.id)
    #redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Successfully created book reservation."
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
 end
```

it raises `undefined method`build_book_reservation' for nil:NilClass` error

---

model/book_reservation.rb

```
 belongs_to :reservation
```

model/reservation.rb

```
has_one :book_reservation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause of the error is you never set session but you tried to access it.In your application controller use

```
private
 def current_reservation
   @reservation ||= Reservation.find(session[:reservation_id]) if session[:reservation_id]
   #last assigned value will be returned as default.
 end

 def create_reservation_session(id)
   session[:reservation_id] = id
 end

 def destroy_reservation_session
   session[:reservation_id] = nil
 end
```

In your controller

```
 def new
   @book_reservation = BookReservation.new
 end

def create
  @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:reservation_id])
  if @reservation
    @book_reservation=@reservation.build_book_reservation(params[:book_reservation])
    if @book_reservation.save
      #If success set session
      create_reservation_session(@reservation.id)
      #redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Successfully created book reservation."
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
   else
      render :action => 'new'
   end
```

Then whenever you need you can use current_reservation.

Comment: hi tried your suggestion and it worked now it raise different error `undefined method `build_book_reservation' for nil:NilClass` this may be a out of the topic just wondering if you know why this happen just edit my post thanks in advance :)

Comment: Add puts @reservation in your create method and tell me what output you are getting?

Comment: what kind of put like a log? sorry im new in ruby :(

Comment: does the redirect_to line commented?

Comment: i just miss type with my last comment `undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class`

Answer (score 0):

You don't ever put `:reservation_id` in the session.

This means that `session[:reservation_id]` is `nil` and `Reservation.find(nil)` raises that exception you are seeing.

Comment: uhm is this what you mean?  `reservation=Reservation.find(session[:reservation_id])` sorry for my dumbness im currently learning

Comment: Yeah, that's the one. I edited the answer to try and be more clear.

Comment: thanks just a follow up question i just edit my post i am doing it right?

Comment: That should fix the immediate problem but now you are going to have issues if someone comes to a page that doesn't post back a reservation_id because params[:reservation_id] might not be there either.